# Nameserver not updating client cache

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, amazon-route53

I've changed nameserver records for my domain name, migrating the dns to AWS Route53.
I've updated the dns a week ago, changing the value for the cname record "mail.". I can see it working fine while other members of the team still see the old destination. The current TTL is 3600 (don't know what it was before to change nameserver), but I can't really figure out how can I force them to see the new destination (now it's a week I set the new record). It seems they are still quering the old namespace, or the cache dns server they are hitting is not up to date with the changes...

What do you suggest to handle this situation? It may afflict also other visitors for our website.

This is the output I get running `dig +trace +norec a mail.mydomain.com`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> +trace +norec a mail.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           3600    IN  NS  FWDR-58.FWDR-0.FWDR-253.FWDR-207.
.           3600    IN  NS  FWDR-62.FWDR-0.FWDR-253.FWDR-207.
.           3600    IN  NS  FWDR-41.FWDR-17.FWDR-37.FWDR-85.
.           3600    IN  NS  FWDR-83.FWDR-28.FWDR-38.FWDR-85.
;; Received 354 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 112 ms

mydomain.com.       4870    IN  NS  ns-1538.awsdns-00.co.uk.
mydomain.com.       4870    IN  NS  ns-243.awsdns-30.com.
mydomain.com.       4870    IN  NS  ns-1531.awsdns-63.org.
mydomain.com.       4870    IN  NS  ns-800.awsdns-36.net.
;; Received 235 bytes from 85.37.17.41#53(85.37.17.41) in 348 ms

mail.mydomain.com.      300 IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com.
;; Received 59 bytes from 205.251.197.251#53(205.251.197.251) in 66 ms
```

Comment: It's not my fault if none of the answers for my prev questions were not working. btw I accepted 1 answer that has received more votes on a suggestion I asked for.

Comment: Please provide some output from dig commands like "dig +trace +norec a mail.example.net." using your domain name instead of example.net (replace your domain name back to example.net in the output if you need to keep your domain unexposed).

Comment: @Skaperen Hi, thanks for the interest. I added the output from the command you suggested to the question above.

Comment: The DNS looks OK so far. At this point more needs to be explored, both from your perspective and other people's perspective. We may need to know the actual domain for this case. Or you may need to get someone on-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that people seeing the old webserver was caused by a record they specified directly inside /etc/hosts, where they declared the IP resolution. So querying the record they were not able to reach the DNS.

By removing that lines and flushing the local dns cache all went right.

Hope this helps someone else having the same issue.